# The Proper Way to test a custom Rails Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have 4 models

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :b
  has_many :c
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :c, through: :d
end

class C < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :b, through: :d
end

class D < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
end
```

I want to test that when making a `d` model that the `b` and `c` both belong to the same `a`.  The question is:

For `rspec` is the best way to test this a simple "valid case/invalid case" test as follows:

```
it "should be valid if both B and C have the same A" do
  a1 = A.first
  b1 = a1.bs.first
  c1 = a1.cs.first

  d1 = D.new(b: b1, c: c1)
  expect(d1.valid?).to be_truthy
end

it "should be invalid if B and C have different A's" do
  a1, a2 = A.first(2)
  b1 = a1.bs.first
  c1 = a2.cs.first

  d1 = D.new(b: b1, c: c1)
  expect(d1.valid?).to be_falsey
end
#assuming that there is test data in the test database
```

or is there a better/more complete way to test that this validation is occurring?

Comment: Actually, it is enough. Additionally you could test your `errors` object if you want to be sure that your messages is included properly.

Comment: Use `expect(d1).to be_valid` and `expect(d1).to_not be_valid`. Do not use `truthy` or `falsey` when you can use methods that returns booleans (e.g. `valid, present, empty`).

Comment: @yzalavin Thanks for the response, I wasn't aware of the `be_valid` options that will definitely help, but overall I just had a nagging thought that this was a bit of a cop-out in terms of testing and wasn't complete.